# How to populate 3 D String Array using Sql server table

Tags: c#, .net

I need to populate 3D String array using sql server table. SQL server table has 3 columns.Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using `SqlCommand` to query from the table? It should be quite straight forward

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask